# Anthology TV series, episodes include people forced to dance, waking up from a virtual reality and an acidic rain

Tags: story-identification, tv

When I was younger, I watched these really weird shows whenever my parents were asleep. I vividly remember 3 of the episodes and, despite googling all of the pieces I recall, the show is nowhere to be found.

There was one episode about a club where the dancers were kidnapped, presumed dead, and were drugged and I think being shocked to dance. One girl found this out and I think it was her sister or her friend. That's all I remember.

Then there was one about a simulation pod. Someone (either a brown haired man or a blonde woman- I can't remember) came out of her pod due to it malfunctioning and she found that she was in a giant row of people stuck in simulated realities.

The last one I remember is about a child's birthday party. There was cake on the far side of the table, right by the edge. The woman went back in for something and it started to rain. There was something wrong with the rain, like really acidic. It started to melt everyone's skin.

I thought they were Twilight Zone episodes, but I've went through all of the descriptions and could not find it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  We don't know when you were younger; approximately what year was this?  Where did you see them?

Comment: The first one sounds like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dance_of_the_Dead_(Masters_of_Horror)

Comment: While there has not been a complete answer posted yet, don't forget to visit the [tour], which will tell you how to accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Answer (score 9):

Partial answer, memories one and three sound like "[Dance of the Dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dance_of_the_Dead_(Masters_of_Horror).)", an episode of *Masters of Horror*, based off of the story by the same name by Richard Matheson.

> At that point, Peggy witnesses what the performance is. The MC has collected the bodies of overdosed teens, called LUPs (Living Undead Phenomenon, or "loopies") injecting them with a drug that causes their hearts to beat twice as fast as normal resulting in convulsions and seizures. This drug was first discovered in the battlegrounds of the war, so the dead soldiers could get up and keep fighting. They are then pumped with blood and forced to dance, and those who can't move are shocked with electric prods. Peggy watches in horror as the MC brings out her own sister, Anna.

The acid rain incident may have been from [another part of the episode](https://www.imdb.com/review/rw1376235/?ref_=tt_urv):

> Peggy just might be the last innocent girl left in a post-apocalyptic world. Nine years earlier, Peggy watched as a rain of toxic chemicals maimed, scarred and/or killed her friends at her seventh birthday party.

### Trailer

However, there are no simulation pods involved.

Answer (score 6):

Partial Answer:-

I don't know about stories one and three, however story 2 reminds me strongly of the new Twilight Zone episode "Dreams for sale" from 1985.
Is it possible the OP watched different series back in the day?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreams_for_Sale_(The_Twilight_Zone)